# Update only 1 component instead of all in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

In this code there are 2 drop downs. I am also trying to perform similar function. My project has 2 drop downs but each one should have separate values when I change the value. If I use this code then the value is same for both the drop downs. What should be changed ?

I am doing react for the 1st time so I don't know even the basics properly.

```
import React from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const styles = {
  customWidth: {
    width: 200,
  },
};

export default class DropDownMenuSimpleExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 1};
  }

  handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Never" />
          <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
          <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
          <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
          <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
        </DropDownMenu>
        <br />
        <DropDownMenu
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          style={styles.customWidth}
          autoWidth={false}
        >
          <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Custom width" />
          <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
          <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
          <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
          <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
        </DropDownMenu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just define seperate handlers for the seperate `DropDownMenu` instances

```
import React from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const styles = {
  customWidth: {
    width: 200,
  },
};

export default class DropDownMenuSimpleExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 1};
  }

  handleValue1Change = (event, index, value1) => this.setState({value1});

  handleValue2Change = (event, index, value2) => this.setState({value2});

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value1} onChange={this.handleValue1Change}>
          <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Never" />
          <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
          <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
          <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
          <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
        </DropDownMenu>
        <br />
        <DropDownMenu
          value={this.state.value2}
          onChange={this.handleValue2Change}
          style={styles.customWidth}
          autoWidth={false}
        >
          <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Custom width" />
          <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
          <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
          <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
          <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
        </DropDownMenu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            dropdownA: "someValue",
            dropdownB: "someOtherValue"
        }
    }

    handleChange = (which, event) => {
        this.setState({ [which]: event.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DropDownMenu 
                    value={this.state.dropdownA} 
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(null, 'dropdownB')}
                >
                    <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Never" />
                    <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
                    <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
                    <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
                    <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
                </DropDownMenu>

                <br />

                <DropDownMenu
                    value={this.state.dropdownB}
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(null, 'dropdownB')}
                    style={styles.customWidth}
                    autoWidth={false}
                >
                    <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Custom width" />
                    <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
                    <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
                    <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
                    <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
                </DropDownMenu>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

in particular, I've updated each `DropDownMenu` to use their own field from the parent component's state: `dropdownA` for the first and `dropdownB` for the second. To account for that, I've adjusted the `onChange` call back for each, [partially applying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the callback with the name of the field it should update.